# Is $n_p(G)$ unique for different groups of size $p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

If $G$ has that $|G| = p^am$ where $p$ is prime and $gcd(p,m) = 1$, we have that $n_p(G)$ counts of Sylow $p$-subgroups in $G$. If $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup, by the third Sylow theorem 
\begin{align*} 
n_p(G) &\equiv 1\text{ mod } p\\
n_p(G) &| m\\
n_p(G) &= [G:N_G(P)]
\end{align*}
$n_p(G)$ seems to depend on $G$, and these properties seem to only give possible candidates for what $n_p(G)$ will be. If I am given $G$ and $H$ with $|G| = |H| = p^am$, do we necessarily have that $n_p(G) = n_p(H)$? It feels sketchy to say so, but I can't come up with any counterexamples off the top of my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: take $S_3$ and $C_6$ Both groups of order $6$. And look at the prime $2$.

Comment: If I am correct, $C_6$ has only one Sylow $2$-subgroup. Namely,if looking at $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, we have that $\{0,3\}$ is the only subgroup of size $2$. On the other hand, $S_3$ has $\langle(1\ 2)\rangle$, $\langle(1\ 3)\rangle$, and $\langle(2\ 3)\rangle$. Therefore, $n_2(C_6) = 1$ and $n_2(S_3)  = 3$.

Comment: Yes correct! Well done! Perhaps you can look for other examples and other primes now.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, suppose you have two finite groups $G$ and $H$ of the same order and for every prime $p$ dividing the order of $G$, $n_p(G)=n_p(H)$. Then $G$ and $H$ do not have to be isomorphic! (Example, take two non-isomorphic (non-abelian) groups $P_1$ and $P_2$ of order $p^3$ (see [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/groupsp3.pdf)), $p$ an odd prime and look at $G=C_2 \times P_1$ and $H=C_2 \times P_2$)